# Pandas dataframe sort_values set default ascending=False

Tags: python, pandas

Could be possible to define a property to always set sort_values(ascending=False)?
Using it quite often in descending order then would like to set the default behavior.

Comment: I'd strongly advise against this. Because you would need a deep knowledge of the Pandas source code, and this will confuse other users. And it's not guaranteed to work across versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to declare the settings you often use in the beginning of your code and pass them as kwargs.

Personally I would, however, write it out every time.

```
import pandas as pd
p = {"ascending":False, "inplace":True}


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1,6,2,5,9,3]
})

df.sort_values(by='col1', **p)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   col1
4     9
1     6
3     5
5     3
2     2
0     1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass the standard `pd.DataFrame` and redefine just the `.sort_values` method:

```
class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def sort_values(self,by,axis=0,ascending=False,inplace=False, 
                    kind='quicksort',na_position='last'):
        return super().sort_values(by,axis,ascending,inplace,kind)

foo = MyDataFrame({'z': [1,2,3,4]})
foo.sort_values('z')
#   z
#3  4
#2  3
#1  2
#0  1
foo.sort_values('z',ascending=True)
#   z
#0  1
#1  2
#2  3
#3  4
```

Comment: I don't think this would work with all cases. For e.g. `foo.sort_values(data, 1)`. Here `axis=1`.

Comment: @RahulGoswami Agree, *args are needed.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Sorry, but there's still a liitle caveat. What if `df.sort_values(data, 1, True)`. Then how do we set `ascending=True`. I guess we could check `if len(args) < 2 and 'ascending' not in kwargs: kwargs ['ascending'] = False`. I wonder if there's a better way. Some thoughts?

Comment: @RahulGoswami Cool observation, which incidentally makes the implementation even simpler!

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own wrapper for this

```
def sort_values(df, *args, **kwargs):
    if len(args) < 2 and "ascending" not in kwargs:
        kwargs["ascending"] = False
    return df.sort_values(*args, **kwargs)
```

But you will have to use it as a function. (You can pass other parameters after 1st agument (dataframe).

```
print(sort_values(my_df, data))
```

Comment: `sort_values` takes tons of parameters, some of which are required. While your suggestion makes sense, technically it is incorrect.

Comment: Still not good. One of the arguments is required. Check `help(df.sort_values)`.

Comment: But did you bother to test it? Because surely it does not work.

Comment: Why don't you try to execute your own example `print(sort_values(my_df))`?

Comment: Oh, thats a typo in the example usage:) Its not a big issue to downvote an answer. You could have just corrected me in the comments. I'll update that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the pandas function. but a good alternative would be to wrap it in your own function.

```
def sort_values(df, sort_by):
    return df.sort_values(ascending=False, by=sort_by)
sort_values(data, ['col1']
```

Comment: Try `sort_values(data, ['col1'], axis=1)` or any other call with keyword parameters.